# What's the grammar behind 〜がいなくて寂しい

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I can't understand how 「いる＋寂しい」 means "to miss something" like in 「君がいなくて寂しいよ。」.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 「君{きみ}がいなく**て**寂{さみ}しいよ。」

「いなくて」 is the te-form of 「いない」.  (「いない」, of course, is the negative form of 「いる」.)

One of the functions of the te-form is to express a ***cause-and-effect*** relationship.  Thus, 「いなく**て**」 in this context is pretty much synonymous to 「いない**ので**」 and 「いない**から**」.

Cause: 君がいない ("You are not here.")

Effect: 寂しい ("I am sad.")

So, the sentence literally means:

> "I am sad because you are not here."

A freer translation would be:

> "I am missing you."